# Does x,y attributes of a SVG really work?

Tags: javascript, d3.js, svg

I am working with `SVG` and a bit confused with `x` and `y` attributes of the `SVG` element itself. They do not appear to be working. Here is the code

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    console.log("Ready");

    var svg = d3.select('#container')
    .append('svg')
    .attr({
        x: 0,
        y: 0,
        width: 200,
        height: 100
    });

    svg.append('circle').attr({
        cx: 100,
        cy: 50,
        r: 30,
        'stroke': 'black',
        fill: 'white',
        'stroke-width': 1
    });
});
```

When I change the `x` and `y` of the `SVG`, the `circle` is not moving accordingly. Say I want to start `SVG` at `(20, 10)` inside the parent `DIV`. I know I can move the `cx` and `cy` of the circle but I wanted to know why the `SVG` itself is not moving. Does it forcefully start at `(0, 0)` inside the parent `DOM` element? Then what are the `x` and `y` used for? Any help is appreciated. Thank you.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You cannot move the `SVG` by setting `x`, `y` in your case. The `x`, `y` attributes of `SVG` comes in handy when you want to nest a `SVG` inside another `SVG`. In that case you can move the child `SVG` by setting appropriate `x`,`y` values related to its parent.

If you really want to align the `SVG` in your case, you may have to use `CSS` to do that.

Read more [here](http://sarasoueidan.com/blog/nesting-svgs/).

Comment: Cool, if the solution solve the problem please do accept the answer. :)